# SonataMediaBundle : allow user to upload link

Tags: php, symfony, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I am fairly new to symfony and I am currently doing a school project with it.

I have to make a functionality where my users can upload youtube link video (like a blog post but with a video). So I decided to use sonataMediaBundle to handle the upload of my links.

I have SonataAdminBundle and SonataUserBundle already installed. It allows me to have my CMS already set up but I found that only the admins can upload links and I can't found how to allow my users to upload link video without give them access to all my CMS in SonataMediaBundle.

Ok I'm progressing on my project, I making it simply (without Sonata).I've got one problem with doctrine, I can't retrieve my database objects.

I followed the symfony doc so I have my "showAction".

```
public function showAction($id)
{
    $video = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('MediaBundle:Media')
        ->find($id);

    if (!$video) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No video found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    return $this->render("MediaBundle:LinkUpload:linkupload.html.twig", array(
        'video' => $video,
    ));
}
```

Then in my template I'm doing:

```
{% for item in video %}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

I also tried without the id parameter and use findAll() instead of find() but I always get an error telling that my variable "video" does not exist.

Any idea about that ?

And I also would like know: how do you properly upload a youtube link video ? I was thinking about put a  tag and ask the user to upload embed youtube link every time but is it not to complicated to do that ? (for the users I mean).

Thanks in advance for your upcoming answers !

Comment: you shouldnt need a bundle to do that. Its a simple case of creating an entity to hold the data, then rendering that data into a template afterwards.  Have a go, and if you get stuck let us see what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved ! I was returning another method before my showAction method so that means my showAction method was returning nothing !